# Mock object queries

Tags: junit, easymock

1. Is it possible to create a mock object with constructor arguments. For e.g 
   Say I have an object and uses two kinds of constructors. How ?

   ```
   Class test{
   List<String> list
   public test()
   {
     list = new ArrayList<String>()
   }

    public test(List<String> list)
    {
     this.list = list
    }
   }
   ```

Question 2: 
Can I use expect on a real object if one of its methods returns a mock object
For e.g PreferenceService prefServ = easyMock.create(...) Now prefServ is a mock object which is returned by one of the methods in class 'Test' E.g. PreferenceService getPreferenceService(). If I create a real object of type Test can i use expect(test.getPreferenceService()).andReturn(mockPreferenceService) ??? I get an error that says incompatible return type.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is partial mocking.  You could do:

```
PreferenceService prefServ = createMock(PreferenceService.class);
Test defaultTest = createMockBuilder(Test.class).addMockMethod("getPreferenceService").
    createMock();
expect(defaultTest.getPreferenceService()).andReturn(prefServ);
```

Now you have defaultTest, instantiated with the default constructor, which is a real instance of Test except that the method getPreferenceService() is mocked.

```
List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
Test otherConstructorTest = createMockBuilder(Test.class).
    addMockMethod("getPreferenceService").withConstructor(testList);
expect(defaultTest.getPreferenceService()).andReturn(prefServ);
```

Now you have the same as above, but this time the Test object was constructed with the List constructor.